# Prefetch link during animation

Tags: javascript, caching, browser, navigation

I'm  trying to make a website have smoother page transitions so I'm using an animation 
to fade out the page and fade in the new page.

I use this bit of javascript to assure the page gets faded out first before the actual navigation
happens:

```
var menu  = document.getElementsById("menu");
var links = menu.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ) {
    (function(link){
        addEvent(link, "click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();                
            addClass(main, "fade-out");
            setTimeout(function(){
                location.href = link.href;
            }, 300);
            return false;
        });
    })(links[i]);
};
```

As you can see from the `setTimeout` call the animation takes about `0.3s` (the actual animation is defined in the `css` file with class `.fade-out`).

Although the animation works very nice, it seems a bit wasteful to not use the animation 
time for already starting to fetch the url that was clicked.

How can I accomplish this? Mind you there are several thing to notice here:

- The navigation is an actual browser navigation (not a javascript replacing of the contents
  of the current page).
- I don't think just initiating an ajax request in the background would work, since
  this might nog finish in the `.3s` available and thus will get aborted by the browser.
  The browser will then refetch the page again (and no gain is made).
  It could be I'm mistaken on this though.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [link prefetching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_prefetching).

> A web page provides a set of prefetching hints to the browser, and
>   after the browser is finished loading the page, and after an idle time
>   has passed, it begins silently prefetching specified documents,
>   storing them in its cache. When the user visits one of the prefetched
>   documents, it can be served up quickly out of the browser's cache.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_prefetching

Comment: This is not necessarily a question about prefetching. I think this is a problem that is (sort of) perpendicular to browser prefetching. The problem is that when I have a lot of menu items the one that is clicked will not necessarily be prefetched already (when using simple `<link rel=prefetch>` tags). Unless there is a way to tell the browser '*hey, start fetching this link immediately*' this will not do.